# Android Studio 4 getting RuntimeException Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-studio

After fresh download of android studio 4.0 getting **RuntimeException** and **ClassNotFoundException** on simple Hello World WearOs apps. Successfully build the project but in installation time getting this error. I tried all possible solution from google search, but didn't work any solution for me.

My Gradle script for app module :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.minimumwear"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.7.0'
}
```

My ActivityClass :

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }
}
```

My Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.minimumwear">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And My error log looks like :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.minimumwear/com.example.minimumwear.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.minimumwear.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.minimumwear-Obx1w-cp5WLQr4-dZvR-ng==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.minimumwear-Obx1w-cp5WLQr4-dZvR-ng==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

And

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.minimumwear.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.minimumwear-Obx1w-cp5WLQr4-dZvR-ng==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.minimumwear-Obx1w-cp5WLQr4-dZvR-ng==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: shar your activity class

Comment: @ShaluTD update my post with activity class.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the IDE, some old files not worked properly. You should have to remove those files.

C:\Users%USERNAME%
.android
.gradle

After removing those items, make sure you first create a new project not opening an existing project.

After successfully finished Gradle Build, run App on your device.

Then you can open your old projects and make some changes in these Gradle files:

build.gradle(Project)

```
 dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
     
         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
         // in the individual module build.gradle files 
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
 #Sun May 03 10:02:16 IST 2020 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I just try this but didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.minimumwear"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

       // Enabling multidex support.
          multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

application:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { 

 }
```

Comment: After try your solution giving new error.  Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\rafsan.jany\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8a55be9a76db64d45e700baa899d2225\jetified-wearable-2.7.0-runtime\classes.dex

Comment: Can you send your code to my email? javaddehban1@gmail.com

Comment: It's not possible now. If you need any information please say, I try to my best.

Comment: Okay, I think I know the answer.

Comment: Then share your idea.

Comment: This problem only for windows. In mac It's working fine.

Comment: Is this a blank project ??

Comment: Yes empty project with one TextView .just Hello World.

Comment: download project in link: https://easyupload.io/opy01e

Comment: Did you know that you must run on a smartwatch?

Comment: YES ! This is WearOS App.

Comment: I run this project on my smartphone and I encountered exactly the same error as you.